# type: 'ckeditor' doesn't work in EasyAdminBundle

Tags: ckeditor, symfony-2.3, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I'm follow the guide on [To Integrating IvoryCKEditorBundle in EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/ivoryckeditorbundle.html), I'm using Symfony 3.1.10 version and EasyAdminBundle 1.17.12 
I put on AppKernel

```
new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(), //CK Editor
```

and just like say in the documentation

```
easy_admin:        
entities:         

    Genus:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Genus
        label: Genuses
        help: Genuses are not covered under warranty!            
        form:
            fields:
                -
                    property: id
                    type_options: {disabled: true}
                - name
                - speciesCount
                - { property: funFact ,  type: ckeditor  }
                - isPublished
                - { property: 'firstDiscoveredAt', type_options: { widget: 'single_text' }}
                - { property: 'subFamily', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete' }
                -                   
                    property: genusScientists
                    type: 'collection'
                    type_options:
                        entry_type: AppBundle\Form\GenusScientistEmbeddedForm
                        allow_delete: true
                        allow_add: true
                        by_reference: false 
                - { property: 'funFact', type: 'textarea' }
```

I config the property funFact for use ckeditor but does not work 
[image of the form with funFact without ckeditor on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNydX.jpg)

in web profile of easyAdminBundle this parameter is put as texarea and not appear nothing about ckeditor [web profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsdK.jpg)
Hope yours could help me , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake I don't see I put at the end again

```
- { property: 'funFact', type: 'textarea' }
```

and that replace the property heheh